# Is it ever appropriate to join two strings using the plus sign (+) over concatenating with curly brackets ({}) and `format` in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, concatenation, string-formatting

I'm trying to write clean and concise code, and in a lot of code I look over sometimes I see people are inconsistent in their code. What I'm asking is, is there ever an instance where this

`print("Cars on the road: " + cars)`

is more appropriate than this

`print("Cars on the road: {}".format(cars))`

or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Personally, I like using `+` when only one or two are needed since I think it's more readable. This is probably a matter of preference though. Some people might like to stay entirely consistent.

Comment: [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation) might help

Comment: maybe this will help [why is s better than for concatenation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big functional difference between the two examples you gave is that when you concatenate with `+`, the operation will fail if the object on the right side of the operand is not a string:

```
"abc" + object()
```

For instance will cause the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't convert 'object' object to str implicitly
```

This is true even if the object on the right side implements the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method:

```
class Foo:
    def __str__(self):
        return "str"
```

Using format however will automatically convert a passed argument using the `__str__` method:

```
"{}".format(Foo()) # "str"
```

There are some situations where this behavior might not be desirable or necessary, such as when you are simply concatenating a string literal with an object that is expected to be a string.

In all other cases I agree with the [post cited in the comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation) which provide plenty of good reasons why formatting is more idiomatically correct and potentially more efficient.

Comment: Nowadays with f-strings there's no excuse

Comment: Yes, this is a game-changer in 3.7, I recently upgraded from 3.6 just for that feature. Sadly the OP is stuck on 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

if you **know** you are dealing with simple strings, then, yes, *Simple is better than complex*. Formatting capability is great, and something like

```
“lit1” + var + “lit2”
```

is a definite code smell.

Your example isn’t and the extra complexity of the template based version is a slight extra cognitive load which **I** would avoid, or at least not strive for, despite using templating extensively.